# Why do we use 2-valued logic (True / False) instead of for example 4-valued logic (Boolean Algebra on two elements powerset)?

Tags: logic

Consider the Boolean algebra ([Power-set of two elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Examples)) with elements $0,1,a,b$. Define $p \implies q$ as $\neg p \lor q$. Then by "brute force computation" (see the attached sage script) we get:
The boolean algebra satisfies:

1) Law of the excluded middle ($A \lor \neg A$)

2) Law of contraposition  $(A\rightarrow B) \iff (\neg B \rightarrow \neg A)$

3) Reductio ad absurdum: $((\neg A \rightarrow B) \land (\neg A \rightarrow \neg B)) \rightarrow A$

4) de Morgan's law: $\neg(A \land B) \iff (\neg A \lor \neg B)$

5) Syllogism: $((A \rightarrow B) \land (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$

Why do we use in "mainstream mathematical proofs" 2-valued logic (True / False) instead of for example the 4-valued logic (Boolean Algebra) if both logics seem to satisfy "useful" axioms.
What would change if one uses the 4-valued logic (Boolean Algebra) in proofs?

Thanks for your help!

Attached Sage script:

```
from sage.all import *


o = set([]) 
a = set([0]) 
b = set([1]) 
l = set([0,1]) 

ba = [o,a,b,l]

def nicht(x):
    return l.difference(x)

def und(x,y):
    return x.intersection(y)

def oder(x,y):
    return x.union(y)


def implies(x,y):
    return oder(nicht(x),y)

def equal(x,y):
    return oder(und(x,y),und(nicht(x),nicht(y)))

# law of excluded middle:
for A in ba:
    print A, oder(A,nicht(A))==l

# law of contraposition:
for x in ba:
    for y in ba:
        print x, y, implies(x,y)==implies(nicht(y),nicht(x))

# reductio ad absurdum
for A in ba:
    for B in ba:
        print A,B, implies(und(implies(nicht(A),B),implies(nicht(A),nicht(B))),A) == l

# de morgans law
for A in ba:
    for B in ba:
        print A,B, nicht(und(A,B))==oder(nicht(A),nicht(B))

# syllogism:
for A in ba:
    for B in ba:
        for C in ba:
            print A,B,C, implies(und(implies(A,B),implies(B,C)),implies(A,C))==l
```

Comment: What do you hope to get by using 4-value logic? How would you interpret a truth value of $a$?

Comment: What would there be to be gained? This is equivalent to classically investigating an $a$-theory, where $1$ and $a$ are true and $0$ and $b$ are false, and a $b$-theory where $1$ and $b$ are true and $0$ and $a$ are false. So could we perhaps investigate the theory of abelian and non-abelian groups in parallel? Sure, just the same way as we do now: We prove statements about all groups, and prove additional statement under the additional hypothesis that our group is abelian ...

Comment: @MarkKamsma: I am not sure. I thought of for example $0=$ provable false, $1=$ provable true, $a=$ not provable but false, $b=$ not provable but true? I am not sure however, if this would be of any use.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I don't know, this question is out of curiosity. See my comment to markkamsma, for a possible truth-value assigment to $a$ and $b$

Comment: Provable/nonprovable and true/false shouldn't me mixed. The former is syntax and the latter is semantics. We do want theorems that relate the two, like soundness and completeness, if possible.

Comment: IMO we actually used a 1 valued logic, and anything without that one value (true) is not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can interpret classical propositional logic (CPL) into *any* [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)). We also have soundness and completeness with respect to this interpretation. That is, a theorem of CPL is provable (with respect to some typical proof system, e.g. the propositional fragment of the sequent calculus **LK**) if and only if it evaluates to the unit/top element of any Boolean algebra. You can actually prove completeness from soundness and the [Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra) with this approach to semantics.

That said, it is much harder to (directly) show that that some formula interprets to the top element for *every* Boolean algebra than it is to show it for some particular Boolean algebra. In particular, the Boolean algebra on a two element set is *extremely* simple. It also turns out that CPL with usual proof systems is complete with respect to it too. In other words, instead of checking *all* Boolean algebras, it suffices to check this one extremely simple one.

And that's pretty much it. It is definitely useful to know that you can interpret CPL into *any* Boolean algebra, but, for the purposes of logic, no (closed) CPL formula can distinguish amongst them. If all you care about is establishing provability/validity, there's no reason to consider anything other than the two element Boolean algebra.

(As a matter of terminology, we don't use $2$-valued logic in proofs<sup>1</sup>, we use proof systems that don't care what the semantics are at all. You could say we use classical logic, but as you've just illustrated, that doesn't depend on being $2$-valued.)

<sup>1</sup> Also, as a fairly subtle point, you can have a $2$-valued logic that isn't classical.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer (+1). But why do proofs by contradiction start with assume $A$ is false, then get a contradiction, so $A$ _must_ be true (law of excluded middle), if $A$ could be assigned more than two truth values. I don't understand that. Of course you could argue, that the two valued Boolean Algebra is the most simple, but this does not exclude the possibility of having more than two truth-values assigned to a variable.

Comment: That's not what proofs by contradiction do. They assume $\neg A$, show that that leads to a contradiction, and hence conclude $A$. Again, proofs say nothing about semantics. There is no "$A$ is false" or "$A$ is true" as far as proofs are concerned. If you do interpret it into a Boolean algebra, you'll find that the interpretation of $\neg A\to\bot$ is $A$ regardless of whether $A$ is interpreted as the top element, bottom element, or some other element. You may find [this blog post](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/the-pedagogy-of-logic-a-rant.html) of mine helpful.

Comment: thanks for the hint