# Youtube suggestions for learning mathematical logic

Tags: logic

There is a bunch of lecture series on youtube about mathematical logic. Are there some videos you have found to be particularly good? And that you could recommend?

Comment: If you want to learn in any math subject (logic in your case), one advice is that you get acostumated to search information in various internet ressources. One of the most useful internet ressource is the universities classes (MIT for example). Creating a www.archive.org account might be useful as well if you want to read books online. They have a good range of math books available.

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about mathematical logic, you might consider reading some books on the subject. Some popular books on mathematical logic include "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Elliott Mendelson, "A Course in Mathematical Logic" by Sergio Fajardo and Edwin H. Lorch, and "Mathematical Logic" by Ebbinghaus et al. You can also check out some online resources, such as Khan Academy, which has a number of lessons and exercises on logical reasoning and proof techniques.

I hope this helps. Good luck with your studies!

Answer (score 0):

For YouTube videos specifically, I recommend [Charlotte Aten's lectures on Universal Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JNn-vggUH4&list=PLkNMPCqtfFRTbWTgXabLJZGnyt7koG8KR).

I don't know exactly what you're trying to learn about in logic, but universal algebra comes up in two or three ways:

1. Universal algebra studies models of [equational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic), which is like a special case of [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).
2. Universal algebra is used in [abstract algebraic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebraic_logic) to study propositional logics and probably some other things too.
3. Lattices come up a lot when studying logic. This is sorta the same thing as 2.

For 2, Lloyd Humberstone's book *The Connectives* uses some universal algebra in the beginning to define what connectives are and what a logic is syntactically. I learned about this book from [an answer Noah Schweber wrote on a question I asked about two years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3981978).

---

Also, Richard Borcherds makes a lot of videos. There isn't a series directly related to mathematical logic, but [his series on axiomatic set theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7pMHqIIdbc&list=PL8yHsr3EFj52EKVgPi-p50fRP2_SbG2oi) is cool.

---

There's also [this series of videos on Model Theory by Piotr Kowalski](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5NTBa75CoM&list=PLoWHl5YajIf5ZwhGrgiZkM_9X_UGCkbm7). I started watching those a while ago, but haven't watched the whole series end to end.

---

When it comes to logic, there's also three other broad flavors of video content that I'm aware of:

1. Philosophical talks about logic. Examples include [Hitoshi Omori's talk on Connexive Logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcdcKb8nH5Y), [Greg Restall's Course on Logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTAcRSnObdw&list=PLvROQ_RldgC8KYmkQsF_zKqAXD_Xphr9n), [Graham Priest's Lecture on Paraconsistent Logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jo1TbN0M3xc).
2. Computational approaches to specific logic problems. [Video on answer set programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDjmqycSy_o).
3. Category Theory and Type Theory -- this is a big area that I only dimly understand, I'll flesh out this section later.